# Swift Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: swift, xcode

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
        self.label1.text = (snapshot.value as AnyObject)["label"] as! String
    }, withCancel: {
    error in
    print(error.description)
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Line `}, withCancel: {` shows a compiler error:

> cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type
>   '((Error) -> Void)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
        self.label1.text = (snapshot.value as AnyObject)["label"] as! String
    }, withCancel: {
    (error:Error) -> Void in
    print(error.description)
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: This would be a really good answer if there was an explanation of why the OP was getting the error and how your code fixed the error.